# Permisos para enviar Mensajes de Texto (enviar SMS)

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy tratando de enviar mensajes de texto desde mi app y usando un dispositivo físico con Android 6.0 (Moto G 3rd generation), este es el código que uso:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("12345678" , null,"hello world" , null, null);
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me lanza esta excepción:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.globalsiag.sms_global, PID: 22364
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10113 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:813)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:310)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:293)
at com.globalsiag.sms_global.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:88)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Por qué no funcionan los permisos?, debo solicitarlos por ser Android 6.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece que de acuerdo a el mensaje de error, el problema es debido a que usas la clase incorrecta:

```
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
```

debe ser:

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

> **android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager** es obsoleta desde la API 4.
>   Reemplazada por **android.telephony.SmsManager** que soporta GSM y CDMA.

#### Como enviar un mensaje SMS.

Únicamente necesitas especificar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
String phone = "1234567890";
String text = "Hi from Stackoverflow.com";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
```

#### Para Android 6.0

se requiere garantizar el permiso, para esto puedes usar el siguiente método:

```
private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisé y sí tengo la clase correcta:

`import android.telephony.SmsManager;`

Comment: tu mobile tiene soporte teléfonico, es decir puedes realizar llamadas? cual es el minsdk y targetsdk de tu proyecto?

Comment: Sí, es mi teléfono personal. Estos son los datos:

`minSdkVersion 15`
`targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: Ya encontré el error y es por permisos, pero cómo se habilitan los permisos en mi dispositivo físico, porque la App no me solicitó ninguno?

Comment: tienes que tener el permiso de mi respuesta, pero usas un dispositivo con Android 6.0 ? para editar mi respuesta

Comment: Sí, se me pasó por alto decir que es Android 6.0

Comment: @castellbot, Agregue la forma de obtener los permisos.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó!