# Enviar SMS Android

Tags: android, sms

Hola quisiera que por favor me ayudaran. Quisiera saber como hago para enviar un SMS al presionar una opción en un menú. este es el código muchas gracias.

```
package com.servitecnology.servigps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu;
import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.OnMenuSelectedListener;
import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.OnMenuStatusChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleMenu circleMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

        circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.icon_menu, R.mipmap.icon_cancel);
        circleMenu.addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.icon_home)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.icon_search)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.icon_notify)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.icon_setting)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
                  .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps);


        circleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                                                     switch (index) {
                                                         case 0:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor Encendido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 1:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor Apagado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 2:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sirena Encendida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 3:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sirena Apagadada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThankYouActivity.class));
                                                             break;
                                                         case 4:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Microfono ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 5:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Microfono OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 6:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Buscando Ubicacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 7:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rastrerando Ubicacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                         case 8:
                                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Microfono OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             break;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }

        );

        circleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onMenuOpened() {

                                                     }

                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onMenuClosed() {

                                                     }
                                                 }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (circleMenu.isOpened())
            circleMenu.closeMenu();
        else
            finish();
    }

}
```

---

Los hice de esta forma y no me envia el SMS

```
CircleMenu circleMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

    circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.icon_menu, R.mipmap.icon_cancel);
    circleMenu.addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.icon_home)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.icon_search)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.icon_notify)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.icon_setting)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps);


    circleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

                                             @Override
                                             public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                                                 switch (index) {
                                                     case 0:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor Encendido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         String phone = "3012229034";
                                                         String text = "Hi from Stackoverflow.com";
                                                         SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                                         sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
                                                         break;
                                                     case 1:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         break;
                                                     case 2:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Notify button Clciked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         break;
                                                     case 3:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings button Clcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThankYouActivity.class));
                                                         break;
                                                     case 4:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         break;
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }

    );




    circleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onMenuOpened() {

                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onMenuClosed() {

                                                 }
                                             }
    );
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (circleMenu.isOpened())
        circleMenu.closeMenu();
    else
        finish();
}



private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Recuerda agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta mediante la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/135475/edit), si usas android 6.0 o posterior debes requerir los permisos manualmente, revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: Estoy probando con android 4.4

Comment: Si me funciono amigo muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvio te sugiero marcarla como respuesta revisa [tour] @DeivisBarrios saludos

Answer (score 5):

Para enviar un SMS aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
String phone = "1234567890";
String text = "Hi from Stackoverflow.com";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
```

Puedes ver más información en la siguiente pregunta, donde también se define como requerir permisos para dispositivos OS6.0+:

[Android 6.0 - Permisos para enviar Mensajes de Texto (enviar SMS)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8480/android-6-0-permisos-para-enviar-mensajes-de-texto/8481#8481)

Ahoria si lo que deseas es por ejemplo enviar el SMS al dar click en la primera opción (indice 0) del menú se realizaría de esta forma:

```
...

   switch (index) {
            case 0:
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor Encendido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  String phone = "1234567890";
                  String text = "Hi from Stackoverflow.com";
                  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
             break;
...
```

**Muy importante tu dispositivo soporte telefonico y es importante agregar el numero correctamente.**