# Enviar un mensaje de whatssap sin acceder a la aplicación (Android studio)

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy creando una aplicación en android studio y quiero enviar un mensaje de whatssap, sin necesidad de acceder a la aplicación, a un número específico. Inicié usando la Api de whatssap pero leí que con esta no es posible hacer lo que deseo. Me gustaría saber si hay otra solución a mi situación. Abajo dejo el código que actualmente estoy usando.

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  String uri = "whatsapp://send?phone=523323495386&text=hola";
  sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
  startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Segun se con el intent puedes enviar un SMS pero pasando por abrir abrir la aplicación, ten en cuenta que dejar esa via libre permitiría crear aplicaciones sobre la de Whatsapp.

Comment: Tal vez puede interesarte leer [¿Como puedo enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp a un contacto especifico desde otra aplicación android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a)

Answer (score 0):

Si no deseas abrir la aplicaciòn Whatsapp es no es posible actualmente, no lo permite la api, pero en cambio si desde una app android deseas realizar el intent para abrir Whatsapp y enviar el mensaje si lo puedes realizar.

Se puede de la forma que tratas pero es muy importante agregar el signo `+` antes del nùmero, seguido por el còdigo del paìs por ejemplo mi país actual es México +52, y agregas el código de área por ejemplo para Guadalajara, Mexico es 33 y posteriormente agrega el telefono:

:

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  String uri = "whatsapp://send?phone=+523323495386&text=hola";
  sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
  startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: No sabes si de casualidad hay alguna otra forma? por ejemplo,  ya ves que muchas aplicaciones envían códigos de verificación a tu teléfono y supongo que ese proceso lo hacen automático sin alguien que lo envíe.

Comment: Asi es pero no usan la API Whatsapp para enviarlo, podrìas enviar un SMS tambièn , revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135481/95