# Cómo quitar los permisos de SMS y llamadas en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hola he comprado el código de una aplicación y este viene con permisos para mandar SMS y hacer llamadas por la app, pero yo no quiero nada de eso, como puedo quitar esas opciones y evitar que salga el aviso al abrir la aplicación?

> No quiero solo quitar el aviso, quiero quitar esas características de
>   envio de SMS y llamadas telefonicas de mi app.

Veo que en `AndroidManifest.xml` puedo ver los `<uses-permission`, pero nose si borrando eso será suficiente.

Comment: En principio con eso tendría que valer, pero claro entiendo que si piden esos permisos es que usan esa funcionalidad por lo tanto puede fallar la aplicación. También se puede pedir permiso en tiempo de ejecución si no recuerdo mal.

Comment: Eliminando los permisos en el AndroidManifest eliminas la posibilidad de usar esas características. Pero como te ha dicho IDanny si tu aplicación pide permisos lo normal es que los utilice, por lo que tendrías que ver donde usas SMS y llamadas y eliminar esas partes del código si no las quieres. Te recommiendo leer la sección Uso de permisos de esta página: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions, seguro que te será de ayuda.

Comment: Saben donde pueden estar esas funciones para borrarlas? la verdad que no las necesito y quisiera que mi aplicación sea lo menos pesada y molesta posible.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando a el usuario se le requieren ciertos permisos, estos permisos fueron definidos en el archivo manifiesto, el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, si no deseas que estos permisos se requieren al usuario simplemente no los definas.

Para [enviar SMS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8480/android-6-0-permisos-para-enviar-mensajes-de-texto-enviar-sms/8481#8481):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Para [realizar llamadas telefónicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13443/permisos-para-realizar-llamadas-compatible-con-android-6-0-y-versiones-anteriore/13444#13444):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**es suficiente con no definirlos dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`**, aunque tengas código que revise si los tienes o los requiera (android 6.0 o posterior) este no será llamado. **Es importante tomar en cuenta que debes revisar si estos permisos son esenciales para el funcionamiento de tu aplicación.**