# Envío SMS no se envía pero informa éxito en la operación

Tags: java, android, sms

Uso el código siguiente para enviar un SMS. El problema es que la aplicación indica que el mensaje se ha enviado correctamente, pero realmente ni se envía ni aparece en la lista de SMS enviados, y no encuentro donde puede estar el problema.

```
public void enviar(String numTelefono, String mensaje) {

        if (mensaje.length() > 160) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sms_limite_max, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try {
                SmsManager smsMgrVar = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsMgrVar.sendTextMessage(numTelefono, null, mensaje, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sms_ok,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sms_sin_permiso,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tu código es correcto, asegura los 4 puntos que indico en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**El código que muestras es correcto, pero considera que para lograr enviar mensajes SMS debes cumplir estos punto**s:

• El dispositivo desde donde deseas enviar el  mensaje debe tener soporte teléfonico.

• Debes definir el permiso `SEND_SMS` tanto dentro del AndroidManifest.xml como realizar la petición manualmente, puedes ver más información:

[Permisos para enviar Mensajes de Texto (enviar SMS)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8480/permisos-para-enviar-mensajes-de-texto-enviar-sms/8481#8481)

• Debes usar la clase SmsManager que soporta GSM y CDMA.

• Definir correcamente el número y mensaje.

Ejemplo:

```
String phone = "1234567890";
String text = "Hola desde Stackoverflow.com";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He revisado los puntos que me indicas y están todos correctos. Los permisos están aceptados y el mensaje es inferior a los 160 caracteres. Voy a probar añadiendo un PendingIntent para monitorizar el envío y ver que ocurre, ya que no lo conocía.

Answer (score 1):

Probá agregando un *PendingIntent*

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
smsMgrVar.sendTextMessage(numTelefono, null, mensaje, sentPI, null);
```

Lo que estas haciendo es imprimir el **Toast** luego del `sendTextMessage()` por lo que si el llamado no tira un **IllegalArgumentException** siempre vas a mostrar el mensaje de éxito.

Al usar **PendingIntent** podés saber si el mensaje se envió correctamente o falló. Por lo que luego de ejecutar el `sendTextMessage()` podés saber el código resultante y sólo mostrar tu **Toast** si es igual `Activity.RESULT_OK`.

La especificación de los distintos mensajes de error las podés encontrar [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager)

Comment: En este caso no se necesita un PendingIntent, el receptor es otro dispositivo con soporte teléfonico, no hay forma de revisar si se recibe Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: Tenés razón no me detuve en ese detalle. Debería eliminar la respuesta o editarla para dejar la parte del porque le aparece el Toast diciendo que está todo bien?

Comment: Gracias. No entiendo bien por qué no se necesita el PendingIntent. Quizás con esto me indique done está el problema. Haré pruebas y os comento.

Comment: Pues ya funciona. Sólo añadí el PendingIntent para ver más información y resulta que ya funciona. No me lo explico pero parece que ahora si va bien.